# Get date from dates range in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, date

I want to get all dates when I have a dates range.
For example: when I have two dates: `2010-10-05 and 2010-10-10` I want to get

```
2010-10-05
2010-10-06
2010-10-07
2010-10-08
2010-10-09
2010-10-10
```

Have anyone got an idea how to get this in MySQL query?

Comment: Please kindly update your question, it does not provide any schema details, expected & understandable output, please

Answer (score 0):

As it requires a loop, you need to create a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html).

There you can simply iterate over the days:

```
DECLARE my_date DATE;
SET my_date = my_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```